# Is it possible to override the ObjectContext.SaveChanges method in entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I was wondering if it is possible to override the ObjectContext.SaveChanges() method and write our own sql logic to save the changes made to the entities in the object context instead of relying on Entity Framework to save those changes in the database.

Comment: Question is, Saving Changes will simply be either Insert, Update, Delete, which EF will and does do it correctly and any validation you want to carry, you can carry before saving them. What exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can do anything you want if you override `SaveChanges` and do not call `base.SaveChanges` but you will loose all the stuf EF will do for you. It means you will have to manually browse metadata and map your entities to SQL tables and columns. There will be like writing half the ORM yourselves.

If you just need some little custom logic when persisting entity you can map imported stored procedure to Insert, Update and Delete operations in the entity designer.

Answer (score 1):

In EF4 `SaveChanges(SaveOptions)` is virtual. You can override this method. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395500%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: And before you start. Take a look on the original one with reflector :).

Comment: Thanks. but my question is: "can we write our own sql logic to save the changes made to the entities in the object context instead of relying on Entity Framework to save those changes in the database."

Answer (score 0):

@Ladislav is correct that a stored proc is one way to do this (+1).

Another way is to write a [wrapper provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32).